# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split' when getting input works with debugger but not with vsCode terminal

Tags: python

Having some issues with my code, would be great if you can help me out

**Function of code:**.
Calculate the dot product between two vectors

```
def dot_product():
    vector1 = input("Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: ").split(",")
    vector2 = input("Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: ").split(",")
    result = 0
    for item in zip(vector1, vector2):
        result += (int(item[0])*int(item[1]))
    return vector1, vector2, result

print(dot_product())
```

**Problem**: Every time I run this code I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/premium.py/Chapter1/work.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(dot_product())
  File "/premium.py/Chapter1/work.py", line 26, in dot_product
    vector1 = input("Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: ").split(",")
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Now it was working fine before but now it isn't. I have tried doing:

```
vector1 = str(input("Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: ")).split(",")
vector2 = str(input("Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: ")).split(",")
```

But I am still getting same error.

When I run it with the python debugger console it works fine and I don't get any issues.

But when I run it with the normal code It doesn't work.

Btw I just installed **code-runner extension**, don't know if that has anything to do with it

an error of

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    python -u "/premium.py/Chapter1/work.py"^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

every other time I try to run it.

Please can you help me understand thanks

Comment: your code doesn't throw an error for me. ```Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: 1,2,3
Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: 3,3,2
(['1', '2', '3'], ['3', '3', '2'], 15)```

Comment: It works perfectly in Colab.

Comment: It works perfectly in windows terminal (v 3.10)

Comment: There is no issue with the code. Please provide the inputs vector1 and vector2 correctly.

Above two comments are correct. I tested with Pycharm as well.

Comment: I enter it like this: 8, 5, 1. I think something wrong with the file I am working in idk.

Comment: This should work as well.

Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: 8, 5, 1
Enter your vector in the form of: x, y, z: 8, 5, 1
(['8', ' 5', ' 1'], ['8', ' 5', ' 1'], 90)

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Ok, it works in pyCharm but not Vscode, think I must of done something when I installed the extension, yeh I remove extension and it works hmm.

Comment: sorry for all the fuss guys

Comment: It sounds like you're running it with Python 2, where `input()` would evaluate (!) the input instead of keeping it as a string, so `8, 5, 1` would become a tuple. I can't explain why it worked when you converted to `str()`, but possibly you forgot to save the file before running it, or something.